# TYPO3 fluid array key increment by 1

Tags: typo3, fluid

In fluid template I am displaying items list

```
<f:for each="{myItems}" as="myItem" key="key">
   {key}. myItem.name
</f:for>
```

Here I need to display serial number for each item.
for example,

```
1. myitem one
2. myitem two
etc.
```

But in my case I used {key} for serial number. But its starting from 0.

```
0. myitem one
1. myitem two
```

So how to increment key by 1 for displaying only ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `iteration=""` property and then `cycle`. It starts from 1 instead of 0.

```
<f:for each="{myItems}" as="myItem" iteration="itemIterator">
   {itemIterator.cycle}. myItem.name
</f:for>
```

tip: `f:for` iterator contains other useful properties, like `isFirst`, `isOdd` etc.

[Check the wiki for more datails](http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f%3afor)

Comment: Thanks for the extension. The link is very usefull here.

Answer (score 5):

In Fluid standalone and TYPO3v8 and above:

```
<f:for each="{myItems}" as="myItem" key="key">
   {key + 1}. myItem.name
</f:for>
```

The key (no pun intended) is the MathExpressionNode and any implementation of Fluid which intentionally disables this implementation will not support this expression - in those cases, `iterator.cycle` is your friend.